# .svelte-kit/tsconfig generated file references the wrong directory for $lib

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have an issue where the generated `tsconfig.json` file referencing the wrong path for $lib

The configuration generated references directory one level up.

`.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
    "$lib": [
        "../src/lib"
    ],
    "$lib/*": [
        "../src/lib/*"
    ]
},
```

It should instead reference the current directory.

```
"paths": {
    "$lib": [
        "/src/lib"
    ],
    "$lib/*": [
        "/src/lib/*"
    ]
},
```

Dependencies

```
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.1.3",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^1.0.4",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.1.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl": "^1.0.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint": "^8.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "prettier": "^2.8.3",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.9.0",
        "sass": "^1.57.1",
        "svelte": "^3.55.1",
        "svelte-check": "^3.0.2",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4",
        "vite": "^4.0.4",
        "vitest": "^0.27.1"
```

I have not changed or added any configuration in `svelte.config.js`, `tsconfig.json`, or `vite.config.ts`. What could be causing this?

I have tried setting the alias in `svelte.config.js` to override the $lib alias according to the docs. Also modifying `vite.config.ts` to resolve with alias (which is now not needed with the new alias update).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the paths.

The file is in the subfolder `.svelte-kit`, so `..` will go back to the root where `src` should be.

(There used to be a `baseUrl` set to `..` which was removed in [this PR](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/8568).)

Comment: The issue I am facing is that when I have an import like so:

`import {myComponent} from "$lib/stores/Auth/myComponent.ts";`

The reference to the component is broken. I get a 'Cannot find declaration to go to'.

However, if I manually change the paths in `.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json` like so, the file resolves correctly. 

`"paths": {
    "$lib": [
        "/src/lib"
    ],
    "$lib/*": [
        "/src/lib/*"
    ]
},`

The path not resolving is an issue because I am not getting the type information and checks. Do you have any insight as to what is happening?

Comment: I never had any such issues. You might want to raise that in the respective repository on GitHub, fully explaining how one would reproduce that.